# Is there a general notion of nonabelian cech cohomology?

Tags: reference-request, homology-cohomology

Diving into the theory of vector bundles and characteristic classes, I've often come across the introduction of $\check{H}^1(\mathcal U, Gl(n))$, where $\mathcal U = \{U_i\}_i$ is an open cover of a space $X$, as the orbit space of coboundaries $(\delta_i)_i$ acting on cocycles $(g_{ij})_{ij}$ by morphing each $g_{ij}$ to $\delta_i \,g_{ij}\, \delta_j^{-1}$.  However, this seems like an isolated workaround to the fact that the coboundary map $(\delta_i)_i\mapsto (\delta_i\delta_j^{-1})_{ij}$ may not be a group homomorphism in general, which is due to $GL(n)$ being nonabelian for $n>1$.

Of course, the outlined approach works to construct $\check H^1(\mathcal U, G)$ for *any* nonabelian group $G$.

*But is there a reasonable definition for the higher cohomology classes?*

Please bear in mind that I know nothing about algebro-geometrical methods such as sheaf cohomology, if that's relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no higher cohomology classes if $G$ is nonabelian. $H^1(X, G)$ computes (under mild hypotheses) the set of homotopy classes of maps $X \to BG$ where $BG$ is the [classifying space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classifying_space) of $G$. When $G$ is abelian $BG$ can be modeled as a topological abelian group so itself has a classifying space $B^2 G$, so this construction can be iterated, which is the abstract reason why higher cohomology exists; under mild hypotheses $H^n(X, A)$ computes the set of homotopy classes of maps $X \to B^n A$.

When $G$ is nonabelian this is (generally) impossible, morally because of the [Eckmann-Hilton argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eckmann%E2%80%93Hilton_argument), although there are subtleties involving the possibility that, say, a nonabelian group is contractible and so "homotopy abelian." In order for $G$ to have a double classifying space $B^2 G$, $G$ must be a [double loop space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_space), or equivalently what is called a grouplike [$E_2$-algebra](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/En-algebra), and most nonabelian topological groups won't have this property.

Comment: could you sketch the idea how to make use of Eckmann Hilton argument to conclude that in general $ H^n(X, G)$ not describes to homotopy classes of $ X \to B^nG$?

Comment: @user7391733: that's not the issue. The Eckmann-Hilton argument shows (morally) that if $B^2 G$ even exists then $G$ must be at least homotopy commutative.

Comment: so the honest input of Eckmann Hilton argument here is really just that loop spaces are commutative? (and therefore the existence of $B^2G $ implies the existence of commutative homotopy model of $ G $ , the double loop space of the former) that's the idea?

Comment: *that loop spaces are homotopy ! commutative

Comment: It's that double loop spaces are homotopy commutative, yes (although stronger statements can be made).

Comment: could you give a quick upshot on in which direction the statement can be made 'stronger'? by less restrictive assumptions on G?

Comment: The stronger statement, which involves a stronger version of the Eckmann-Hilton argument, is that double loop spaces are $E_2$-algebras (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/En-algebra).

Comment: the point which still confuses me a bit is that at the beginning we started with an abstract or topological group $ G $ and the later stronger version deals with $ E_2$-algebras, so from naive point of view higher categoretical objects. do I understand it correctly  that in situations like this we always tacitly endow the 'classical' objects ( like here the group G) canonically with higher structure, ie here a group can be always seen as a groupoid, and a category as $ \infty$-category where the only higher morphisms are the identities?

Comment: Yes, more or less. More precisely the claim is that in order for the notation $B^2 G$ to be meaningful it must be the case that $G$ is homotopy equivalent to the double loop space of whatever this space is. But we also need to say something about the compatibility of the multiplications, and what that thing is, precisely, is that $G$, *regarded as an $E_1$-algebra*, can be endowed with the structure of an $E_2$-algebra.